# WordPress: Loop Multiple Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, categories, taxonomy

I have the following issue, I have two loops on my homepage. 1 loop with two categories and one loop with two tags, but its not working. See my code below:

**Loop 1**

```
query_posts(array( 
'post_type' => 'post', 
'cat' => 12, 15, 
'posts_per_page' => 8)); 
if(have_posts()) : $count = count($r); ?>

<!--POST STUFF HERE-->
```

**Loop 2**

```
query_posts(array( 
'post_type' => 'post', 
'terms' => 'news', 'articles', 
'posts_per_page' => 8)); 
if(have_posts()) : $count = count($r); ?>

<!--POST STUFF HERE-->
```

Comment: Are you running `the_post()`? Also you should use arrays, not comma separated list for `cat` and `terms`.

Comment: Like you said, the code works without the commas and I just use one single cat or term. Im not sure how to add a second though.

Comment: An array: `'cat' => array(12,15)`, same with `terms`.